# OBD II Sample Datasets

Tags: data-request, cars

I'm trying to find sample datasets of [OBD II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) data. OBD II is a data standard for automobile on-board diagnostics,

I'd like a huge set with lots of journeys but right now I will settle for anything.

Looking to get something for testing before i invest in a [simulator like this](https://www.scantool.net/development-tools/obd-simulators/ecusim-2000/).

Comment: Did you find something?, I been looking for datasets for a while

Answer (score 1):

If you're still searching, is here a link to some serious ODB-II dataset : [OBD-II datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/cephasax/obdii-ds3).

Hope I helped.